# Extracting new features from this table for only names that have a total_rate that is negative in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi

[image]

I am trying to build a report from this table where I am only interested in names that have a total of negative total_rate as seen in the output table.
Output

[image]

Comment: Foe the Total_rate why is John -6 and mike -3 what is the logic behind the filter and why is sam excluded?

Comment: Sorry is -5. The reason why sam is exempted is that the sum(total_rate) < 0.

Answer (score 0):

In PBI this is very simple, no magic needed.

Place the table visual on your report, drag the 3 columns in the table. Apply a filter to only include rates < 0. See image below.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input, my interest is the card on top that shows the Total_Rate and Total_size.

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking for, I believe I did what you where looking for?

Comment: Thanks again Albert, can you display the total in a card for size and rate. I tried it but it gave me different values which is different from 12 and -8

Comment: @umagbaalex just put them in a card